# Ionic Sqlite DB Read

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

Noob in the whole ionic + angular scenario and trying to learn some db reading.
I am trying to get a result in to a variable and alert it. But seems like I have missed something. The expected output is being logged in to the console, but the alert simply comes up blank.

Below is my code.

```
$scope.submitlogin = function(){

  var query = "SELECT userpass FROM admin";
  var dbpass = "";
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {

    if(res.rows.length > 0) {
      dbpass = res.rows.item(0).userpass;
      console.log("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(0).userpass);
      dbpass = dbpass + 1;
      console.log(dbpass);
    } else {
      console.log("No results found");
    }
  }, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }); 
  alert(dbpass);
  $scope.modaler.hide();
}
```

All the console logs show the expected result. But the alert towards the end of the code simply gives an empty alert.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might be a scoping issue... Have you tried to alert **directly** after your console.log?

Comment: On second thought it could also be a timing issue. If your handler is called again dbpass will be overridden with ""...